# Sending php $score to another page

Tags: php, variables, post

I need a little help with small php script. I want to pass my $score to another URL.

After visitor submits test through html POST form, he is taken to a page where test score is calculated and displayed:

```
<?php
$answer1= $_POST['answer1'];
$answer2= $_POST['answer2'];
$answer5= $_POST['answer5'];
$answer6= $_POST['answer6'];
$answer7= $_POST['answer7'];
$answer8= $_POST['answer8'];
$answer9= $_POST['answer9'];
$answer10= $_POST['answer10'];
$answer11= $_POST['answer11'];
$answer12= $_POST['answer12'];
$answer13= $_POST['answer13'];
$answer14= $_POST['answer14'];
$answer15= $_POST['answer15'];
$answer16= $_POST['answer16'];
$answer17= $_POST['answer17'];
$answer18= $_POST['answer18'];
$answer19= $_POST['answer19'];
$answer20= $_POST['answer20'];
$score = 0;

if ($answer1 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer1 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}


if ($answer5 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer6 == "A"){$score++;}
if ($answer6 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer7 == "A"){$score++;}
if ($answer7 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer7 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer8 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer8 == "B"){$score++;}
if ($answer8 == "C"){$score++;$score++;}


if ($answer9 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer9 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer9 == "D"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer10 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer10 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer10 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer11 == "A"){$score++;}
if ($answer11 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer11 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}


if ($answer12 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer12 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer13 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer13 == "B"){$score++;}

if ($answer14 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer14 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer14 == "C"){$score++;}

if ($answer15 == "A"){$score++;}
if ($answer15 == "C"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer15 == "D"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer16 == "B"){$score++;}
if ($answer16 == "C"){$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer16 == "D"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer17 == "B"){$score++;}
if ($answer17 == "C"){$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer17 == "D"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer18 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer18 == "C"){$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer18 == "E"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer18 == "F"){$score++;$score++;$score++;}

if ($answer19 == "B"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}
if ($answer20 == "A"){$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;}

echo "$score";

?>
```

On that page, where the echo "$score"; is displayed, visitors have to click this form button to activate a service:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">

<input name="pass" type="text" id="pass" />

<input type="submit" style="font-weight:bold" name="Submit" value="Aktiviraj!" />        </form>
```

After clicking the button they are being taken to another .html page, **where I actually want the test echo "$score"; to be displayed again.** Basically I want page A to pass (send) echo $ score to page B, without involving MySql base in the process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could store the score (ha) in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: 1. use sessions; 2. man there is **SOME** code smell in your script...

Comment: use `$score += 4;` instead of `$score++;$score++;$score++;$score++;`

Comment: This needs some major refactoring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name='answer[0]'/>
<input name='answer[1]'/>
<input name='answer[2]'/>
<input name='answer[3]'/>
<input name='answer[4]'/>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['score'] = 0;
//If you aren't using a DB backend
$answers = array(
    0 => array("A"=>4,"B"=>1),
    1 => array("A"=>4,"B"=>1),
    2 => array("A"=>4,"B"=>2,"C"=>0),//and so on

);
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $key => $value)
{
    $_SESSION['score'] += (int)$answers[$key][$value];
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how transfer the calculated score to a new page.

Comment: Yes it does. If you add the function to whatever page, you can just add the score to that page using it. There are obviously much better ways to write this code, but for the sake of getting it working the way he wants quickly, this would do just fine. There is no reason that this logic *NEEDS* to be in it's own file. And if it does, it could just be an include.

Comment: This answer implies that the answers should be posted and recalculated every time. It's not only a terrible solution, but doesn't answer the question as to how to transfer a variable from one request to another. The correct solution here would be a session, database backend or similar.

Comment: Agreed. I changed this up.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [sessions](http://php.net/sessions) to transfer your calculated values between requests.